# Remove element from html using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

i am new to jQuery.

i have list element as follows.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="abc">ABC</a>
    </li>
    <li> <!-- I want to remove this element-->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="def">DEF</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="ghi">GHI</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i want to remove LI element (commented in above sample) which has GHI anchor tag using jQuery.
or in other ways i want to remove that element based on the href property or text contained in the anchor tag.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

```
$("ul:first > li:eq(1)").remove()
```

Select the first ul, then remove the second li child.

Or if you meant the li with GHI  tag,

```
$("ul:eq(1) > li:eq(1)").remove()
```

Select the second ul, and find the second li child.

Comment: Thanks, but it will not always be the case. i want to remove the element based on the text in anchor tag or href attribute of anchor tag.

Comment: @PrateekDeshpande: Based on this comment, I have added my answer - it removes `<li>` element containing anchor with `href` equal to "`ghi`".

Answer (score 2):

To remove `li` element placed somewhere above the anchor with `href="ghi"` you could do something like this:

```
jQuery('a[href="ghi"]').parents('ul > li').remove();
```

or if `li` element that needs to be removed is not the direct child of the `ul` element (good point, mrtsherman):

```
jQuery('a[href="ghi"]').parents('ul li').remove();
```

See it in action: [jsfiddle.net/tadeck/EmZ4N/](http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/EmZ4N/)

Comment: I like this one the best. Most of the other answers provided are just wrong. There is the assumption that `li` being removed is a direct child of the `ul`, but OP didn't specify alternate cases.

Comment: @mrtsherman: Thanks, I have added the case when `li` we want to remove is not the direct child of `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove li with certain href(s):

```
$('li > a[href^="abc"]').remove();
```

That is selecting all list items that contain anchors with hrefs that begin with "abc" and then removing them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href="ghi"]').closest('li').closest('li').remove();
```